# JEvents Frontend 'Download as iCal file' not working

Tags: joomla-3.4, modal, jevents

My site here: http://aycliffe.kent.sch.uk/icalrepeat.detail/2015/09/18/351/newspaper-with-mr-durrant

I am unable to use the button 'Download as iCal file' the modal window appears but then goes again straight away - I've tried debugging it but can't find anything obvious.

Unfortunately, the JEvents forum isn't allowing posts using URLs at present!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem being is that you are importing Bootstrap 2.x which comes shipped with Joomla (coming via `<jdoc:include type="head" />`) **and** Bootstrap 3.3.5 via the following link:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

which I assume you've manually added or is coming from the component.

You've also got the following jQuery snippet somewhere in the head which could be causing issues:

```
if ($('#ical_dialogJQ351').length) {
    var bootstrap3_enabled = (typeof jQuery().emulateTransitionEnd == 'function');
    if (bootstrap3_enabled && $('#ical_dialogJQ351').hasClass('hide')){
        $('#ical_dialogJQ351').removeClass('hide');
    }
    //$('#ical_dialogJQ351').appendTo('body').modal({"backdrop":true,"keyboard":true,"show":true,"remote":""});
}

if ($('#action_dialogJQ351').length) {
    var bootstrap3_enabled = (typeof jQuery().emulateTransitionEnd == 'function');
    if (bootstrap3_enabled && $('#action_dialogJQ351').hasClass('hide')){
        $('#action_dialogJQ351').removeClass('hide');
    }
    //$('#action_dialogJQ351').appendTo('body').modal({"backdrop":true,"keyboard":true,"show":true,"remote":""});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, I've just switched off the jQuery Easy plugin and it's now working! Thanks for your help and reply as always! :)

Comment: @RustyJoomla - You're welcome ;)